# Redux Saga: loading indicator for a sign in button

Tags: redux-saga, saga

We use the following saga to signup the user by phone:

```
function* signup() {
    while (true) {
        const {phone} = yield take("APP_SIGNUP");

        nav.toCode();

        const responseSignup = yield call(fetch.signUp, phone);

        if (!responseSignup.success) {
            yield put({type: "SIGNUP_SERVER_ERROR"}); 
            continue;
        }

        let i;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            const {code} = yield take("APP_CHECK_CODE");

            // MARKED LINE
            const {success} = yield call(fetch.checkCode, {
                phone,
                code,
            });

            if (success) break;
            yield put({ type: "APP_CHECK_CODE_WRONG" });
       }

    // code ok
    if (i < 3) {
        nav.toTabs();
        yield put({ type: "APP_CHECK_USER" });
    }
 ...
```

The user enters his phone number and is shown a screen in which he fills the 4-digit code - you know the drill.

We want to add a loading indicator. Is there a way to return a promise to whoever called the APP_CHECK_CODE action*?

*marked in the code with "MARKED LINE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a promise from a thunk, but if you want to stick to with sagas, there is no simple way to let the component that dispatched the action know that the saga is finished other than changing redux store state.

So the way I would go around this is to use a reducer such as:

```
export (state = {checkingCode: false}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case APP_CHECK_CODE:
            return {...state, checkingCode: true};
        case APP_CHECK_CODE_WRONG:
        case APP_CHECK_CODE_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, checkingCode: false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And then show/hide the loading indicator based on the `checkingCode` value.

*Theoretically, you could pass something like an observer to the saga and then wait for that, if you really want to keep the state in the component itself.*

```
// component
const observable = Observable.create(observer => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    dispatch({type: APP_CHECK_CODE, observer});
});
observable.subscribe({
  complete: () => this.setState({loading: false}),
});


// saga
const {code, observer} = yield take("APP_CHECK_CODE")
...
observer.complete();
```

*But honestly, that feels very magical and would imo lead to more trouble than its worth.*

Comment: You could've used a callback instead. If you're going to pass an extra field to the action creator, why not pass a callback function that can get called from the saga to indicate it's complete? Spares the use of an entire library.